# Android Fragment management

Tags: android, user-interface, android-fragments

I am learning Android Apps development and [in this](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Transactions) guide, the API makes it clear a `Fragment` can be managed in at runtime, so far you have the fragment's id or tag.

But [this tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html) in the other hand says you can only deal with fragments at runtime IF you don't declare them in the XML.

I find this very confusing...Which one is right?

Comment: On the first things I'd clarify with Fragments is that they don't necessarily contain UI elements, so having a fragment in the xml layout is definitely optional. The Android tutorial you refer to never says what you're saying. Which part of the doc makes you understand that?

Comment: I never said I understood `Fragments` need a UI, I am just saying one tutorial says IF you declare one in the UI using the `<fragment>` tag you can't change it at runtime and the other tutorial doest says anything about this, leaving the reader to understand that it's fine to modify it at runtime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you declare a fragment in a XML layout with the `<fragment>` tag, you cannot replace it dinamically at runtime.

If you declare in xml layout a container(FrameLayout) for different fragments. Using `FragmentTansaction` you will be able to add a fragment to that container and then replace it or remove it at runtime. As you will see in the [Building a Flexible UI](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html#AddAtRuntime) lesson:

> In order to replace one fragment with another, the activity's layout
>   includes an empty FrameLayout that acts as the fragment container.

Comment: Yes, that's what the second tutorial I posted says....BUT the first one makes no mention on it, and it even shows some methods to find a fragment by id or by tag to modify it at runtime, hence my question

Comment: That's because you can also find the fragment created with <fragment> tag, so you can have a reference to it, and e.g. call a public method it declares to execute an operation. But, you cannot use that reference to remove it by executing a FragmentTransaction, the code will compile and execute without errors, but the fragment won't be removed.